# Java- Test for Word

Tags: java, authentication

I am using NetBeans and the code is

```
    private void passwordActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)     {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:  
    }
```

How to make java scan for a certain password, so that, if it is wrong it does not work and if the password is correct it works and performs an action.

Comment: Show what else have you tried... Its not clear what you want... Paste at least minimal code that can be compiled and verified

Comment: I am asking what I have to write in that code so that it looks for password and sees if it is right

Comment: Simply on your event firing take value from a textbox or passwordbox first then do your further manipulations... Would have been better if you showed your whole code... Would have helped you out

Answer (score 0):

You should have an simple text/password input field awt, read the input into a variable and simply compare it with a if.

Comment: From the question, it's fair to assume that the OP knows that they _should_ have a password field - this answer pretty much paraphrases the question, up to the "How" part. Could you add a solid example that demonstrates how to access the password and make a simple comparison that results in an appropriate return value? It's certainly fair to say "BTW - plain text passwords are bad, 'mkay?" - not your job to solve the problem that hasn't been presented, but helpful to point it out.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use NetBeans. Use Eclipse instead and code the way you want the window to appear, don't make the gui by drag-n-drop

Comment: I guess the upvotes are from NetBeans haters, because this makes no attempt to answer the question about how to validate the password. (The OP could do all you say, and will STILL have the problem that brought them here.) Maybe you could show code demonstrating how it would be done without the NB D&D GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it is not too late to reply for this. If so then another one who refers this may find this answer helpful.

For your particular question the answers is that you simply can use an if statement to perform this.

Assuming that your password jPasswordfield is "**jpassText**" and your password is "**abc123**"

```
   if(jpassText.getText().trim().equals("abc123")){
        System.out.println("Password is correct");
   }else{
        System.out.println("Please re-try");
   }
```

For the sake of learning this is fine. But if you move into a login screen there are several steps to be followed.

step 1 : get the username and the password

step 2 : trim them and check for empty strings

step 3 : check whether the user is available in the database (of course you should keep a db and query for the user details from it)

step 4 : encrypt the password and compare both username and the password with the table and if success grant the login else let the user try again.

When saving passwords it is better to encrypt them so that it is not saved in plain text. When querying, user entered password should be encrypted with the same algorithm it was saved to the database and compare the encrypted password string with the queried password.

This practice can be followed even when you try to give some administrative facilities inside your application for certain group of users.

Hope that helps.